# Simple Constraint Programming Problem: docplex works but equivalent ortools model is infeasible

Tags: python, constraint-programming, or-tools, docplex, cp-sat

I have a simple constraint programming model which can be solved using the `docplex` library, however I am struggling to implement the same model using `ortools` (see the examples below).

**Question:** Is there a fundamental limitation of `ortools` which prevents implementing this solution, or is there a problem with my syntax?

**Note:** I am NOT interested in alternative problem formulations, e.g., reformulating this as an MIP. This is a toy problem and I know different formulations are possible. *My goal is to understand the differences and limitations of different solvers when it comes to implementing a constraint like this.*

## Problem

Given a series with indices `0...n`, find integer values of the series such that the value for each index `i` corresponds to the number of occurrences of `i` in the series.

For example, a solution for `n = 4` is:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 0 | 0 |

For index `i=0`, the value is `2`, which corresponds to the series "2, 1, 2, 0, 0" containing two occurrences of the value `0`. Index `i=1` has a value of `1`, corresponding to the single occurrence of `1` in the series. And so on.

## Example input data

```
# Input: Series length
n = 5

# Define data
max_value = n - 1
NUMBERS = range(n)
```

## `docplex` implementation works!

```
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel

# Model instance
model = CpoModel(name='find series')

# Decision variables
s = model.integer_var_list(n, 0, max_value, "series")

# Constraint: Value should equal the # of occurrences of the index in the series
for i in NUMBERS:
    model.add(sum(s[j] == i for j in NUMBERS) == s[i])

# Solve
model.solve()
```

## `ortools` implementation does NOT work!

When attempting to run the code below, I get an error when I try to define the constraints:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'BoundedLinearExpression'`.

I've tried adjusting the syntax a few different ways, but it never reads the constraint as I intend it to.

````
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

# Model instance
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# Decision variables
X = {}
for i in NUMBERS:
    X[i] = model.NewIntVar(0, max_value, f'X_{i}')

# Add constraints (CODE FAILS HERE)
for i in NUMBERS:
    model.Add(X[i] == sum([X[j]==i for j in NUMBERS]))

# Solve
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model)

# Solution
print('Solve status: %s' % solver.StatusName())
if solver.StatusName() in ['FEASIBLE', 'OPTIMAL']:
    for i in NUMBERS:
        print(f'  X_{i}: {solver.Value(X[i])}')
```
````

Comment: You are trying to do sumif in ORtools. I am no expert in Google language but have you double checked if sum in a constraint under a condition is implemented in that way? Does ORtools give an lp file that shows the model?

Comment: Per Laurent Perron's accepted answer, ORtools can implement a constraint like this using something called a "channeling constraint". It's not very intuitive to me, but it seems like the way to do a conditional sum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Please read [this doc section](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/docs/channeling.md)
2. cp-sat prefers Boolean variables. Here is a c++ [version](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/cpp/magic_sequence_sat.cc).